# Showing a .txt or .xml file in tapestry 5

Tags: java, tapestry

I recently started working with tapestry. I have a text file named robots.txt, in src/main/resources in my tapestry app.

I want the file to be shown when I type the URL : `localhost:8080/robots.txt`.

How do I do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an Index page in the root of your application

```
package foo.bar.mybasepackage.pages;

public class Index {
    public Object onActivate(EventContext context) {
        if (context.getCount() == 1
                && "robots.txt".equals(context.get(String.class, 0)) {

           return getRobotsTxt();
        }
        if (context.getCount() != 0) {
           return new HttpError(404, "Not found");
        }
        return this;
    }

    private StreamResponse getRobotsTxt() {
        return new TextStreamResponse(...);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. As I see, I need to put the text as string as parametar to the TextStreamResponse constructor. How can i read the text from the file ?

Comment: Oh, sorry... should have read your question better. I thought you were calculating robots.txt on the fly. Assuming you are following maven conventions, you should just put the file in `src/main/webapp/robots.txt` and forget about the whole Index page thing. If you want to keep the file in `src/main/resources` you could access it via `getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("robots.txt")`

Comment: I moved it to src/main/webapp. I should put the sitemap.xml file in the same place right ? 
Thanks again :)